# rsync - file is 8 bytes larger on recipient

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I have a file that I have tried transferring across the wired LAN via both scp and rsync, and both have yielded the same result. When I run `du file` on the file after the transfer, the file is 8 bytes larger on the recipient host.

I have also checked `head file | hexdump -C` on both hosts, and they are identical. Same story for `tail`...

Any ideas why this might be happening? If it matters, the file is a gzip.

Comment: Balanced usual (yet unnecessary) arse**** downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`du file` is not a suitable way to measure file size. Even the very first line of the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) says « du - *estimate* file space usage » (my italics).

Instead, use one or more of the following methods (others will also exist):

```
ls -l file       # byte size should be the same on both sides
cksum file       # checksum should be same result on both sides
md5sum file      # checksum should be same result on both sides
stat -c %s file  # byte size should be same result on both sides
```